# Mudar o ponto de quebra (breakpoint) do navbar

Tags: css3, layout-responsivo, bootstrap-3, nav-bar, breakpoints

Tenho uma navbar que trabalha com o collapse, pra quando em menor resolução o menu se agrupe e apareça só quando clicado. Enfim, tem como eu mudar o breakpoint somente da navbar para que este efeito ocorra numa outra resolução maior? Tentei mudar no bootstrap.css onde tinha referência a mesma, mas não tive resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altere o `max-width` de acordo com o desejado.

```
@media (max-width: 990px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

Fonte: [Bootstrap 3 - navbar collapsible until 990px](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21687800/bootstrap-3-navbar-collapsible-until-990px)

Exemplo: [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/105915)

Comment: Tentei alterar os itens acima, porém não obtive resultado. Aqui os break points vieram com min-width:768px. Mudei para max width (com a resolução que desejo) mas não resolveu.

Comment: O meu, quando clico, ele abre quando clico, mas logo em seguida ele fecha.

Comment: O meu também está dessa maneira, alguém sabe como resolver?

Comment: @FabioSouza Você conseguiu?

Comment: Resolve o problema da resolução de tela, mas a usabilidade fica inútil pois como disse o @FabioSouza clica e abre, mas logo em seguida fecha.

Answer (score 0):

Bem mais simples do que eu pensei,

Abra o arquivo do bootstrap.css, e utilizando o IDE de preferência é só aplicar um "replace all" para as seguintes strings:

```
@media (min-width:768
```

Trocar por

```
@media (min-width:990
```

Aí a responsividade da aplicação será aplicada quando o tela atingir os 990px

Utilizando a IDE phpStorm:
[image: Utilizando a IDE phpStorm]

Answer (score 0):

Sei que isto não resolve diretamente o problema apresentado, mas realmente não parece uma boa ideia ter breakpoints específicos para apenas um componente quando usual é que todo o layout os siga. Especificamente o Bootstrap 3 possui variáveis que lidam com isso e você pode gerar um [build customizado](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints). Caso contrário, a melhor abordagem é do Rafael Barbosa, aplicando um estilos CSS extras como um *patch* sobre as regras do Bootstrap.