# Modificar breakpoint do navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, menu, nav-bar

```css
nav #btn-principais{
 background-color: #27C8D0;
 border-radius: 1px !important;
 float: right;
}
#logo{
 width: 240px;
 height: auto;
 float: left;
}
nav .icon-bar{
 background-color: #000;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    overflow-x: visible;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}
.collapse {
    display: none;
}
ul .dropdown-menu{
 background-color: #FFF;
}
ul .dropdown-menu li{
 padding: 10px 0px;
 font-weight: 700;
}
ul .dropdown-menu a:hover{
 background-color: transparent;
 color: #27C8D0;
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
.container>.navbar-header, .container-fluid>.navbar-header, .container>.navbar-collapse, .container-fluid>.navbar-collapse {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;}
}
.container>.navbar-header, .container-fluid>.navbar-header, .container>.navbar-collapse, .container-fluid>.navbar-collapse {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: block!important;
    height: auto!important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible!important;}
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
.navbar-collapse {
    width: auto;
    border-top: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;}
}
/* my breakpoint */
@media (max-width: 1224px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
 <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Teste navbar</title>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dropdown.js"></script>
    
<body>

<header>
<div class="container-fluid" id="topo">

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" id="nav-menu">
   <nav class="navbar">
     <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#newNavbar">
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
         </button>    
         <a class="navbar-brand" id="logo" href="#"><img src="logos.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
      </div>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="newNavbar">
         <!--<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="btn-principais">-->
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="btn-principais">           
           <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Link 7</a></li>
         </ul>
       </div>
     </div>
   </nav>
  <!--</div>-->
  
 </div>
 <!-- fim #topo -->


</div>


</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Bom dia pessoal. Precisava de uma ajudinha.
Eu estava precisando modificar meu breakpoint do navbar e consegui achar aqui no forum uma pergunta com essa dúvida juntamente com sua resposta.  Copiei, colei e fui fazer os testes mas enquanto a navbar está reduzida e clico, o menu abre e fecha no mesmo instante.

Essa dúvida também foi questionada lá, porém ninguém soube responder.  Fiz algumas mudanças e testes mas não tive sucesso e por isso vim aqui ver se alguém poderia me ajudar e desde já agradeço.

Link da resposta que achei:
[Mudar o ponto de quebra (breakpoint) do navbar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58519/mudar-o-ponto-de-quebra-breakpoint-do-navbar)

CSS aqui embaixo:

```
@media (max-width: 990px) {
.navbar-header {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
}
.navbar-nav {
    float: none!important;
    margin: 7.5px -15px;
}
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
}
```

Comment: Consegue deixar o exemplo rodando aqui para vermos o erro dele abrindo e fechando?

Comment: @LuizFelipe vou publicar e coloco a url aqui ta bem.  Obrigada!

Comment: Coloca o seu código completo HTML com a `<head>` css etc

Comment: Acabei de colocar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vc está usando uma classe a mais no lugar errado!

Remova a classe `navbar-collapse` nessa `<div>`

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="newNavbar">
```

Deve ser apenas

```
<div class="collapse" id="newNavbar">
```

**EDIT:** para continuar mostrando o Menu normal nas telas grandes tem que colocar `.collapse {display: block;}` antes dos @media e dentro do `@media (max-width: 1224px)` vc coloca `.collapse {display: none;}` Execute o Snippet abaixo que já corrigi isso.

**Veja abaixo o exemplo funcionando sem o BUG** *(não mexi em nada de CSS ou HTML, apenas removi a classe `navbar-collapse` na `<div>`)*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
 <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Teste navbar</title>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dropdown.js"></script>

    <style>
    nav #btn-principais{
 background-color: #27C8D0;
 border-radius: 1px !important;
 float: right;
}
#logo{
 width: 240px;
 height: auto;
 float: left;
}
nav .icon-bar{
 background-color: #000;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    overflow-x: visible;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}
.collapse {
    display: block;
}
ul .dropdown-menu{
 background-color: #FFF;
}
ul .dropdown-menu li{
 padding: 10px 0px;
 font-weight: 700;
}
ul .dropdown-menu a:hover{
 background-color: transparent;
 color: #27C8D0;
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
.container>.navbar-header, .container-fluid>.navbar-header, .container>.navbar-collapse, .container-fluid>.navbar-collapse {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;}
}
.container>.navbar-header, .container-fluid>.navbar-header, .container>.navbar-collapse, .container-fluid>.navbar-collapse {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: block!important;
    height: auto!important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible!important;}
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
.navbar-collapse {
    width: auto;
    border-top: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;}
}
/* my breakpoint */
@media (max-width: 1224px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .collapse {
    display: none;
}
    
}
    </style>
    
<body>

<header>
<div class="container-fluid" id="topo">

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" id="nav-menu">
   <nav class="navbar">
     <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#newNavbar">
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
         </button>    
         <a class="navbar-brand" id="logo" href="#"><img src="http://placeskull.com/100/50" class="img-responsive"></a>
      </div>
       <div class="collapse" id="newNavbar">
         <!--<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="btn-principais">-->
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="btn-principais">           
           <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Link 7</a></li>
         </ul>
       </div>
     </div>
   </nav>
  <!--</div>-->
  
 </div>
 <!-- fim #topo -->


</div>


</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Verdade ... testei aqui e funcionou perfeitamente, sendo que quando a resolução é acima de 990px o menu desaparece :-(

Tenta ver por aí como ficou.  Por aqui vou tentar mexer mais um pouco baseada no que me enviou.  Fico grata e se achar alguma coisa me fala por favor rs

Comment: Fernanda já está resolvido, é que quando vc criou o seu BreackPoint vc colocou MAX-width `@media (max-width: 1224px)` e na verdade vc deveria colocar `@media (min-width: 1224px)` para funcionar em telas grandes. Eu já editei a minha resposta arrumando isso, olha ai

Comment: Se a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marcar como Resolvido usando o **✓** ao lado das setas a esquerda

Comment: Oi Hugo, obrigada mas nesse caso é max-width mesmo porque até 1224px preciso que o hamburguerzinho apareça e acima já vem o menu normal mesmo.

Comment: Fernanda fiz uma edição na minha resposta resolvendo o problema de vez, basta Executar e depois clicar me "Pagina toda" para ver funcionando, ou coloca direto no seu projeto e pode testar. No **EDIT** da minha resposta coloquei a explicação :)

Comment: Que legal, é isso mesmo que eu precisava Hugo ... brigadãaao =)

Comment: Nos embolamos um pouco, mas que bom que deu certo. Boa sorte com o projeto :)

Comment: Que nada ... eu quem me enrolei toda kkkk.  Se não fosse a ajuda de vocês estaria perdida. Obrigada + uma vez e tudo de bom !!

Answer (score 0):

Apenas removi a propriedade `display:none !important` do `.navbar-collapse.collapse` e resolveu. Você removendo a classe `.navbar-collapse` teria problemas no layout. Olha como ficou:

```css
nav #btn-principais{
 background-color: #27C8D0;
 border-radius: 1px !important;
 float: right;
}
#logo{
 width: 240px;
 height: auto;
 float: left;
}
nav .icon-bar{
 background-color: #000;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    overflow-x: visible;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}
.collapse {
    display: none;
}
ul .dropdown-menu{
 background-color: #FFF;
}
ul .dropdown-menu li{
 padding: 10px 0px;
 font-weight: 700;
}
ul .dropdown-menu a:hover{
 background-color: transparent;
 color: #27C8D0;
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
.container>.navbar-header, .container-fluid>.navbar-header, .container>.navbar-collapse, .container-fluid>.navbar-collapse {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;}
}
.container>.navbar-header, .container-fluid>.navbar-header, .container>.navbar-collapse, .container-fluid>.navbar-collapse {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: block!important;
    height: auto!important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible!important;}
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
.navbar-collapse {
    width: auto;
    border-top: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;}
}
/* my breakpoint */
@media (max-width: 1224px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }

    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
 <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Teste navbar</title>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dropdown.js"></script>
    
<body>

<header>
<div class="container-fluid" id="topo">

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" id="nav-menu">
   <nav class="navbar">
     <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#newNavbar">
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
         </button>    
         <a class="navbar-brand" id="logo" href="#"><img src="logos.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
      </div>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="newNavbar">
         <!--<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="btn-principais">-->
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="btn-principais">           
           <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
           <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Link 7</a></li>
         </ul>
       </div>
     </div>
   </nav>
  <!--</div>-->
  
 </div>
 <!-- fim #topo -->


</div>


</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oi Luiz eu dei uma olhada sim, sendo que eu queria que os links do menu apenas surgissem quando clicassem no "hamburguerzinho".  Nesse caso o menu já aparece disponível de uma vez e nem clicando no hamburguer ele não some, continua ali.